# Automatic full screen when video begins to play

Tags: swift, swift3, swift4

I'm using this library in my project (Swift-YouTube-Player) 
Click [Swift-Youtube-Player](https://github.com/gilesvangruisen/Swift-YouTube-Player)!

my question is when i click play button, full screen mode automatically appear. How can i dismiss this ?

Answer (score 0):

please check [player_parameters](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/ios_youtube_helper#control-video-playback)

To always play inline, you need to set the `playsinline` property to 1

```
 var playerVars = ["controls": "1", "playsinline": "1", "autohide": "1", "showinfo": "1", "autoplay": "0", "fs": "1", "rel": "0", "loop": "0", "enablejsapi": "1", "modestbranding": "1"]
myVideoPlayer.load(withVideoId: currentClip.clip_video.video_media_id, playerVars: playerVars)
```

Comment: thanks a lot man =)